# What harm do "invalid entities" do?

Tags: symfony, database-design, doctrine-orm, entity

I am using Symfony 2 with Doctrine. Sometimes when adding new relationships between entities I forget to add the "inversedBy" attribute to the owning entity. This results in "invalid entities" in the debug toolbar and the profiler:

[image: Symfony Profiler showing invalid entities message]

I have not yet encountered any problems due to some entities being invalid. Is there anything that does not work with invalid entities or is the warning message the only reason why I should fix them?

Comment: Is the output of the command `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` that checks the current mappings for valid forward and reverse mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the case that `Doctrine2` knows how to detect those incorrect relationships and more importantly knows how to mitigate the issue. You should, however, fix the relationships as soon as possible in order to prevent future issues, in case they decide to change/remove "smart" logic ;)

Other, more probable reason, is that `Doctrine2` uses those complex relationships when dealing with some extra-complex queries, which you might/might not be using...

Comment: Are *invalid entities* detected by Symfony2 or Doctrine2?

Comment: I have actually encountered the second reason you're mentioning. All was working fine until we had a more complex statement with joins. Unfortunately I don't remember the exact cirumstances to post an example.

Comment: @JovanPerovic: this answer only mentions Symfony2.